# using usb microphone as audio input and 3.5 mm jack as audio output

Tags: pi-3

I am almost done with my Smart mirror project but I have issue with the audio input and output.
I'am using ras pi 3 onboard 3.5mm jack for audio output and usb microphone as audio in.
both are working individually absolutely fine but when I record something using usb microphone I am unable to get the output on the 3.5 mm microphones.
so I would really appreciate some help as soon as possible.I have a demonstration of the project within few days.

---

Answer (score -1):

***Question***

> Using Rpi's 3.5mm audio output jack for output and USB microphone for input.
>
> When using USB microphone, unable to get output from 3.5 mm jack.
>
> Help as soon as possible [before coming] demonstration.

***Answer***

Well, a quick and dirty fix to your problem before the demonstration is the following:

> 1. Forget the Rpi's poor quality audio amplifier circuit through the 3.5mm jack.
> 2. Use an USB sound card for ***BOTH*** audio in (microphone), and audio out (loud sepeaker).

If you are in a hurry to google which USB sound card to use, you might like to read my suggestion in the following post.

[Which USB sound card to choose - tlfong01's answer to an old question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98204/whistle-sound-when-recording-with-usb-sound-card-alsamixer)

[image: usb sound card]