# Raspberry Pi Offline Voice Recognition

Tags: speech-recognition

I have been experimenting with the Raspberry Pi and creating an offline voice recognition bot to recognize the numbers 0 through 9.  The software I am using to accomplish this task so far is SOPARE, however I have been less than successful (spotty at best results when trying to recognize numbers, just guesses random variables).  Next up is for me to try out Jasper Project, however I don't know if i'll be successful there either.  If anyone has any suggestions on what I could use, I would greatly appreciate it.

A few notes on what I am working on (and it's constraints):

1. It has to be functional *without* an internet connection.
2. It has to function with just the RasPi (No other chips that I have to go out and purchase)
3. Program has to be easily re-programmable, (i.e if I need to add more vocabulary I can train it rather easily)

What would be ideal for me would be a voice recognition software that comes pre-programmed to recognize basic numbers (Or can learn them easily)

I greatly appreciate the help.

Best,
-Andrew

Answer (score 1):

As above, I am using the same USB UGREEN "SOUNDCARD" as the RPi boards do not have a microphone jack or interface-- regardless of how you want to look at it.

Getting the right microphone was very key. I had great success with a 3.5mm jack omnidirectional conference microphone. (I had a less happy experience with a clip on lapel microphone that I basically had to yell at before the audio could be interpreted by the software.)

I had better results when I made use of /dev/shm for speedier IO.

I liked PocketSphinx on the RPi best.

Tweak and/or thin the entries of the dict file to make things go faster. By limiting the amount of words it can recognize, I made the best performance gains. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cmusphinx/cmudict/master/cmudict.dict

Yeah, that is more or less it. Good luck.

A light warning: /dev/shm is not necessarily a magic bullet-- but, you're using it for a lot of the audio purposes that pulse audio uses /dev/shm for. So, read up on /dev/shm, be smart about what you stuff in /dev/shm, ???, profit.

Answer (score 0):

***Question***

> Rpi offline voice recognition of numbers 0 through 9
>
> No Internet connection, no extra chips
>
> Programmable, eg extend vocabulary
>
> Any suggestions?

***Answer***

Well, can I assume you already have USB microphone or similar?  And since Rpi has not analog to digital, it is impossible to sample and convert voice analog signal.

So I think at least you need some cheap voice input, like the US$2 microphone and power amplifier module below.

And another US$2 for an ADC chip, such as MCP3208 12 bit ADC.

So the ridiculously small budget of 5 dollars is good enough for your ridiculously small vocab voice recognition project.

[image: Microphone module]

[image: Rpi USB Sound Card]

First, some brainstorming ideas.

> 1. Loop a continuous moving average of 100mS to detect start sound trigger signal.
> 2. As soon as sound detected, start MCP3208 to sample voice and do ADC, and stored in RAM and also SD card, say for 1 to 2 seconds, or
>      stop as soon as the moving average goes dead.
> 3. The sample size for a couple of seconds is small, and you can always take less samples per second.  Or do some cheating, small
>      sample when user speak first time, pretend not clear, and heavy sample
>      on user's next try.
> 4. Use simple structured, sequential, statistical analysis tools (DIY or googled) to compare and contrast the 10 (0 to 9) trained samples,
> 5. Can use Python multiprocessing module to compare input data points with 10 standard templates at the same time, discard hopeless
>      templates as soon as possible.

*/ to continue,*

***References***

[Recording sound with Rpi and ADC](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98201/adc-with-raspberry-pi-to-record-sound)

[Using Rpi USB microphone as audio input](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98221/using-usb-microphone-as-audio-input-and-3-5-mm-jack-as-audio-output)

[Rpi USB sound card recording noise problem](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/98204/whistle-sound-when-recording-with-usb-sound-card-alsamixer/98206#98206)

[MCP3008 SPI, 10 bit, 200kps Datasheet - MicroChip](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/21295c.pdf)

[How to amplify voice from microphone in real time? - Old Rpi StkEx post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96756/how-can-i-amplify-my-voice-in-real-time-just-like-a-microphone-does)

[How to make one MCP3008 A/D conversion? - Old Rpi StkEx post](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96143/how-can-i-get-a-fixed-sampling-rate-of-1-ksps-when-interfacing-mcp3008-10-bit-a/96285#96285)

[Differences Between 16-Bit and 24-Bit Audio - Wesley Fenlon 2011mar03](https://www.tested.com/tech/1905-the-real-differences-between-16-bit-and-24-bit-audio/)

[MCP3201/04/08 12bit ADC Datasheets - Microchip](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21298c.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

wblgers on GitHub shows a pretty easy way to setup your own 0-9 speech recognition using a Hidden Markov Model. 
https://github.com/wblgers/hmm_speech_recognition_demo

Check back soon on my page I'll have speech recognition soon using image recognition.
https://github.com/DanielsKraus